# Hive 0.14.0 not starting

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have hadoop 1.2.1 and i have install hive 0.14.0 on single node

```
$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:478)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:430)
... 7 more
```

The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x.

I use `hadoop fs -chmod g+w /tmp/hive` but not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update the permission of your /tmp/hive HDFS directory using the following command

```
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

If so can you remove /tmp/hive on both local and hdfs.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r /tmp/hive;  
rm -rf /tmp/hive
```

Only temporary files are kept in this location. No problem even if we delete this, will be created when required with proper permissions.

Comment: I tried the suggestions in this post but no luck. Then I created the /tmp/hive directory myself and it was created with 755. However, hive still doesn't start. In my case, Hive 0.14 says- `RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxr-xr-x`.  Really funny !!

Comment: Interesting enough, this solved my Hive permission problem: `hadoop dfs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive`. Earlier, I did only **fs**: `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive`

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit of experimentation with this and thought it might be useful to someone.

When hive 0.14.0 is started without first creating /tmp/hive in HDFS, that directory is created with mode 711.

```
drwx--x--x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-12-08 18:47 /tmp/hive
```

If instead one creates the directory via `hadoop dfs -mkdir /tmp/hive` it defaults to mode 755.

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-12-09 11:13 /tmp/hive
```

The minimum permissions required to allow hive to start without errors is 733.

```
hadoop dfs -chmod 733 /tmp/hive
```

Resulting in the following and hive starting successfully.

```
drwx-wx-wx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2014-12-09 11:13 /tmp/hive
```

This leads me to believe that hive 0.14.0 is doing the wrong thing when it creates that directory.

Comment: I agree. I tried the suggestions in the above post but no luck. Then I created the /tmp/hive directory myself and it was created with 755. However, hive still doesn't start. In my case, Hive 0.14 says- `RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxr-xr-x`.  Really funny !!  :-(.

Comment: Interesting enough, this solved my Hive permission problem: `hadoop dfs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive`. Earlier, I did only **fs**: `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive`

Answer (score 0):

Check the value for the below tag on hive-site.xml, then change the permission for the folder mentioned

```
<property>
<name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/mydir</value>
<description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>

hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/mydir;
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/mydir;
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/mydir;
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/mydir;
```